Downgrading python's pip
So, I want to downgrade my pip to version pip==21 in my python virtual enviroment. Problem is, that in most cases it gives me the same error when trying to run that downgraded pip:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 20, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "C:\Users\Jaros\pva_projekt\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six.moves import urllib, map, filter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.six.moves'

The most obvious thing I tried was python -m pip install pip==21. It "Successfully installed pip-21.0", but when I tried to use it, or typed pip --version, it outputted same error. I also tried python get-pip.py pip==21.0, which didn't worked. Then I tried:
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
python -m pip install pip==21.0

And that also made nothing. I also tried this: python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==21.0 without any success. I also tried it outside virtualenv, and it seems to give me same error.

Why exactly do you need to run a version of pip that's older than your version of Python?  What is stopping you from running it on an older version of Python altogether?

Does it work with something like python -m pip install --upgrade pip==21.0?

@Slavensky I tried it, and no, it doesn't.

@Grismar based on this stackoverflow discussion, I need to downgrade to pip==21 in order to install gym library.

If you're using Python 3.10 or newer, it's likely that pip 21.0 isn't compatible with it.

@flexter I'm using 3.13.0, so that will be probably the cause. I'll try it with downgraded version tomorrow.

Installing gym with either Conda or pip poses no problems when using Python 3.10 (on any platform I try). So, why use a version of Python >3.10 when the last release of Gym was for 3.10? Note that you didn't answer the question: what is stopping you from using an appropriate version of Python for your project (if Gym is central to it, that would appear to be 3.10)

So after some issues with pyenv I successfully downgraded to python 3.9.7 and it finally worked. But I still don't know if it is even possible to downgrade pip to pip==21 with python 3.13.0.

So I resolved my problem by downgrading to python 3.9.7, which uses pip version that I needed, but I still don't know what is causing that error, when trying to downgrade pip to pip==21 on python 3.13.0, but as @flexter suggested, it's likely that that pip 21 isn't compatible with this version.
